# Jquery mobile on iphone ios 11 repositions when typing into field

Tags: jquery, iphone, safari, keyboard, ios11

I have a problem that only occurs on iPhone safari. We use jQuery mobile and when trying to type into fields that are on the bottom of my page, it repositions itself for every letter. If i want to see everything i type i have to scroll for each letter. See video. Any ideas on how to fix this ?
I have recorded the issue here:
[you tube video showing issue](https://youtu.be/ZmQGmiS27Ms)

Comment: nice video, but you need post your script

Comment: That field that you are entering text into, are you doing any validation for that field as you type?

Comment: No validation is done in that field. Its is just a multiline textbox

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to remove 2 event listeners from the textarea - for `input` and `keyup` events. I'm doing that on `click` event, like following:

```
<textarea name="mytextarea" onclick="$(this).unbind('input'); $(this).unbind('keyup');"></textarea>
```

hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same problem on iOS 11. Our app is also using jQuery mobile and the textareas are also placed at the bottom of the page. On iOS 10 everything worked find. 
I know it's not a very satisfying solution, but after adding another div after the textarea at the end of the site there is enough space to show the keyboard:

```
<div style="height: 300px"  class="platzhalter"></div>
```

I added also some javascript to hide/show the div on iDevices:

```
var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
if (iOS)
    $('.platzhalter').show();
else
    $('.platzhalter').hide();
```